# MySQL group by desc -how to explain this sql: SELECT ts,avg_time FROM xx WHERE ip="MAX" GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 300?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `api_stats` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `app_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `api_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `avg_time` float(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ok` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `err` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ts` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6741231 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this weird sql is:

```
SELECT ts,avg_time FROM api_stats WHERE ip="MAX" GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 300
```

seems wrong, but it runs...
my questions:

1. select columns is not in aggregate function like sum, count
2. group by id desc is what?

Comment: why is it wrong?

Comment: Who told you that it's wrong?

Comment: update you question with a proper  data sample  ..and the expected result please

Comment: data is much but not important. I mean, in my perspective, it should fail to run for syntax error. but I'm wrong. is auto_increment column special in group by ?

Comment: Read up on only_full_group_by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html, As of  mysql 5.7.5 this is true by default but prior to this mysql allowed a loose group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is a bit dumb.

1. It selects all records with ip = 'MAX' (yes, single quotes should be used for string literals).
2. It groups the results per ID, which doesn't change anything because this is the primary key.
3. It limits the results to 300 arbitrary rows, as there is no `ORDER BY` clause. (In older versions `GROUP BY` was guaranteed to also sort in MySQL, which is why the `DESC` keyword is allowed for `GROUP BY`, which otherwise wouldn't make any sense. So this may have been valid one time and should nowadays read `GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 300` instead.)
4. It shows non-aggregated `ts`, `avg_time`, but well, as mentioned no aggregation takes ever place in this query anyway.

Maybe it's just a typo and `GROUP BY id` was meant to be `ORDER BY id` really, which would make the query perfectly valid (aside from the non-standard quotes that are valid in MySQL however).